# Working out checksum for RS232 connection to fuel meter

Tags: c, hex, checksum

I'm building a python application to communiacte with a fuel meter and the communication protocol requires a checksum for each packet. I dont know C (yes i should learn) and the example is provided in C and I'm trying to reverse engineer it so I can re-write it in python.

I'm at a loss where the actual input is provided in the example below?

An example command looks like this in ASCII, _Q10013 then a 2 byte checksum then a carrriage return.

The example C code looks like this:

```
//! Adjust a byte of checksum for packet to the dfv(emh)
//! @sa CheckSum_emh
uint8_t CheckSumAdjust_emhrx(uint8_t before) 
{ 
    uint8_t after = before;
    if (before == 0x00) after = 0x01;
    if (before == 0x0D) after = 0x0E;
    if (before == 0x5F) after = 0x60;
    return after;
}

//! Calculate checksum on packet transmitted to the dfv(emh)
//! @param ascii_buff Characters in the message to calculate checksum for
//! @param last_char Buffer index of the last character to perform a checksum on.
//! @param chksum Array of where to put the resulting checksum.
void CheckSum_emh(uint8_t ascii_buff[], uint8_t last_char, uint8_t checksum[2])
{
    char i;
    int16_t check_sum;
    check_sum = 0;
    for (i = 0; i <= last_char; i++)
    { 
        check_sum = check_sum + (int16_t)ascii_buff[i];
    } 
    checksum[0] = CheckSumAdjust_emhrx((check_sum & 0xFF00) >> 8);
    checksum[1] = CheckSumAdjust_emhrx(check_sum & 0x00FF);
}
//! end checksum
```

Where does the actual string or hex get provided into the function?

Comment: `ascii_buff` is the input buffer, `last_char` is the length, `checksum` is the output checksum, - in big endian int16.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError Please make this an answer.

Comment: Cheers mate, just a quick one should the ascii_buffer be of type unit8_t that doesn't make sense for an ascii or even a hex string?

Comment: I cant seem to make an answer anywhere?

Comment: @500-InternalServerError "last_char is the length", and `Buffer index of the last character to perform a checksum on.` sounds off-by-one.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica: Yes, correct.